# Finding an image in a folder with subfolders which contains a post value

Tags: php

I am using Jquery to post a value to a page which should then search a folder and its sub-folders to see where the file exists.

The start of the filename will always have something like "HAV_" and then the product code...

```
HAV_345GG.jpg
```

I need to take the posted value which is the product code and search all folders to find a match then return the location as a link ie:

```
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/folder/subfolder/HAV_345GG.jpg
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Is there any logic in folder/subfolder naming wrt the product code? You could traverse your filesystem brute force until you've found the file, but that does not seem a very desirable approach to me.

Comment: No logic, it could be in any folder...its a search to find the part of the file with the product code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to make use of PHPs [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function which returns an array based on a pattern match. This seems like it could be used in this case. You would need to be careful of files with similar names partially matching though such as:

- HAV_123
- HAV_1234

Comment: Would you have any code samples that could help with iterating through the directories?

Comment: I don't I am afraid, but there are a few articles out there such as http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-glob-find-files/ and http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/quick-tip-loop-through-folders-with-phps-glob/ and http://www.phparch.com/2010/04/28/putting-glob-to-the-test/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a lookup table so you can quickly find things by product code.

1. Create a script to rip through all the folders and index the location of the image files by product code. Cache this scripts output somewhere (db, redis memcached, etc).
2. Create a search script that uses the cached lookup table to find the path to the correct file.

You cache might be a PHP array such as:

```
array(
    'ProductCode123' => array(
        '/location/to/image1.jpg',
        '/path/to/image2.jpg',
    ),
    'SerialNumber12233' => array(
        '/some/location/to/image1.jpg',
        '/another/folder/image2.jpg',
    ),
);
```

Without this caching method you are going to find performance to be an issue if there is a lot of files and directories.

A colleague wrote a PHP script called [uberloader](https://github.com/j4mie/uberloader), which does a similar thing but acts a PHP autoloader for disparate file structures such as yours in legacy projects. It is intended to autoload class files but a similar concept of hunting and caching is used.

Comment: Thanks for your help treffy, that seems to make sense!